# How to delete all the column values using Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to delete/clear all the column values using Java? It's required because I am going to write the test report pass/fail automatically, hence before that I want to delete the existing data from Excel sheet automatically, then I want to move further for test report.

I tried many codes but it's not working, hence is it possible to delete all column values after a specific number?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so from what I understood you have an excel file and you want to remove a specific column. This is possible using the sheet.removeColumn( columnNumber ) function.

Suppose you have this code:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Excel.xls"));
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Failures");
```

You can then just simply put in the column number you want to remove and the function will take care of it.

Comment: Hello Jason, I tried all the ways but i didnt found removeColumn option anywhere, so please suggest me on this and also i want to delete all the Existing Column data at once ,Hence is this possible to delete all existing column data at once?

Comment: Try and use this link as a reference, it should work for you. [link](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/java/inserting-and-deleting-rows-and-columns/#:~:text=To%20delete%20a%20column%20from,that%20need%20to%20be%20deleted.)

Comment: I tried this link but need to import utils class, Workbook class and Worksheet class, i was able to find utils class but rest two i am not able to find the Workbook class and Worksheet class, can you please check and let me know if you are able to find it. Thank you.

Comment: Not working and your comment is also not available.